# Waswas during the ghusl

Tags: wudu, ghusl, waswasa

During the ghusl, I always have doubts that I have not fully washed my body. Mostly I think that I have not completely washed my head (because of my long hair) and I have not completely washed my ears. It takes me a lot of liters of water and a lot of time to make a ghusl. On average it takes a little over 20 minutes. The doubts do not stop even after I have already finished bathing. Constant thoughts like "I didn't finish this part of my head", "the water only superficially wet my hair" and so on. What should I do in this situation? Should I go and wash these parts again to get out of the doubt, although even that doesn't always help, or should I ignore these thoughts. If I choose the second option, I already start having thoughts that I am performing the prayer without the ghusl and thus leaving Islam. What should I do?

Comment: "Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor. " And as of my thinking, if your body is reasonable clean (think of what people can do nowadays in comparison with what desert people could manage in the days of the Prophet), it is more important to be in the right spirit for prayer.